# Implementing LSTM regression model with tensor flow

Tags: tensorflow, regression, lstm

I am trying to implement a tensor flow LSTM regression model for a list  of inputs number.
 example:

```
 input_data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
 time_steps = 2
    -> X == [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]]
    -> y == [3, 4, 5]
```

The code is below:

```
TIMESTEPS = 20
num_hidden=20

Xd, yd = load_data()

train_input = Xd['train']
train_input = train_input.reshape(-1,20,1)
train_output = yd['train']

# train_input = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20],..
# train_output  = [[21],[22],[23]....

test_input = Xd['test']
test_output = yd['test']

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 20, 1])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])

cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_hidden, state_is_tuple=True)

val, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, X, dtype=tf.float32)
val = tf.Print(val, [tf.argmax(val,1)], 'argmax(val)=' , summarize=20, first_n=7)

val = tf.transpose(val, [1, 0, 2])
val = tf.Print(val, [tf.argmax(val,1)], 'argmax(val2)=' , summarize=20, first_n=7)

# Take only the last output after 20 time steps
last = tf.gather(val, int(val.get_shape()[0]) - 1)
last = tf.Print(last, [tf.argmax(last,1)], 'argmax(val3)=' , summarize=20, first_n=7)

# define variables for weights and bias
weight = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([num_hidden, int(y.get_shape()[1])]))
bias = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[y.get_shape()[1]]))

# Prediction is matmul of last value + wieght + bias
prediction = tf.matmul(last, weight) + bias

# Cost function using softmax
# y is the true distrubution and prediction is the predicted
cost = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y * tf.log(prediction), reduction_indices=[1]))
#cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=prediction, labels=y))

optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
minimize = optimizer.minimize(cost)

from tensorflow.python import debug as tf_debug
inita = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(inita)

batch_size = 100
no_of_batches = int(len(train_input)/batch_size)
epoch = 10
test_size = 100
for i in range(epoch):
    for start, end in zip(range(0, len(train_input), batch_size), range(batch_size, len(train_input)+1, batch_size)):
        sess.run(minimize, feed_dict={X: train_input[start:end], y: train_output[start:end]})

    test_indices = np.arange(len(test_input))  # Get A Test Batch
    np.random.shuffle(test_indices)
    test_indices = test_indices[0:test_size]
    print (i, mean_squared_error(np.argmax(test_output[test_indices], axis=1), sess.run(prediction, feed_dict={X: test_input[test_indices]})))

print ("predictions", prediction.eval(feed_dict={X: train_input}, session=sess))
y_pred = prediction.eval(feed_dict={X: test_input}, session=sess)
sess.close()
test_size = test_output.shape[0]
ax = np.arange(0, test_size, 1)
plt.plot(ax, test_output, 'r', ax, y_pred, 'b')
plt.show()
```

But i am not able to minimize the cost, the calculated MSE increases at each step instead of decreasing.
I suspect there is a problem with the cost problem that i am using.

any thoughts or suggestions as to what i am doing wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: Try to use the mean square error instead of cross entropy, you're not doing classification here. cost = 0.5*tf.square(y-prediction) ; cost = tf.reduce_mean(cost)

Comment: Hi Anthony,  thanks for the inputs. I tried using MSE as cost as you suggested but the calculated MSE error after each epoch is still increasing.

Comment: I see. Did you try smaller learning rates with the Adam Optimizer ?

Comment: i tried the default 0.1, and then 0.05,0.01, 0.001. But still same behavior. Do you think code in general is ok and should work ?

Comment: Hi Anthony, i repeated my test and both your suggestions really helped. Now the MSE is not exploding (increasing continuously) but fluctuating and the final plot shows that the prediction is reasonably same as the test data. Thanks a lot. There a way to way your comments as answers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, you had to change your loss function to the MSE function and reduce your learning rate. Is your error converging to zero ?

Comment: I have now tested with a toy example dataset using sine function. The MSE fluctuates around a small range (in this case between 0.6 and 0.5) but never decreases below that value. Do you think that for a simple case like sine function it should converge to 0 ?